# Ansible - find the maximum value of a hostvar and the name of that host

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have an inventory with a hostvar that increases:

```
[nodes]
node_0 id=0
node_1 id=1
```

I want to find the highest value of `id` and host that has it. I found another answer for doing the search on nodes with a for loop ([Ansible - Find max value and run action based on a result only on one host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141936/ansible-find-max-value-and-run-action-based-on-a-result-only-on-one-host))  but I need to be able to do this as a local action, since I'm selecting values for node booting on ec2.

Comment: I've edited the question to be simpler and more direct, but, as far as I can tell, it adequately describes the problem I had.  My posted answer provides a working solution I pieced together from other answers on  stackoverflow and Google.   I hope my answer is simple and direct enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

```
- name: Find max id host
  set_fact: id_max_host={{ groups['nodes'] | sort('id' | int) | last }}

- name: Find max id
  set_fact: id_max={{ hostvars[id_max_host]['id'] }}
```

It takes the list of hosts in group nodes, sorts by the hostvar 'id' (which it casts to int, because they're usually strings), and then picks just the last of that sorted list.  Note that if there are multiple identical values, it will pick the last, not the first, though.  I use unique IDs, so it's ok.

This gave me the maximum id number and the name of the host that has it. And it works for both local and remote tasks.  I can use the fact discovered on a remote host to see if this host should run the task assigned to the max ID:

```
- name: Some actions based on a result of previous tasks
  action: # Run some actions
  when:  id_max_host == inventory_hostname
```

or I can use it to make sure all of my newly booted instances are tagged on ec2 with IDs that start at `id_max + 1` and increase:

```
- name: tag instances
  ec2_tag: region="{{ aws_region }}" resource="{{ item.id }}" aws_access_key="{{ aws_access_key }}" aws_secret_key="{{ aws_secret_key }}"
  args:
    tags:
      Name: "node_{{ item.ami_launch_index | int + id_max | int + 1 }}"
      id: "{{ item.ami_launch_index | int + id_max | int + 1 }}"
      with_items: ec2Create.instances
```